# Android Sqlite concat two columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have made the concatenation so far, but in the results, it displays

```
UncleSam.
```

What I want to do is to put a space between the two columns so the result would be

```
Uncle Sam.
```

This is the code I'm working on:

```
   public Cursor getAllPatients()
{
    Cursor localCursor = //  
            this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                    KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME + "||" + KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (localCursor != null)
      localCursor.moveToFirst();
    return localCursor;
}
```

from DBHelper.java

and

```
 Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllPatients();
    String[] data = new String[]{
            DBHelper.KEY_FNAME + "||" + DBHelper.KEY_LNAME, DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS, DBHelper.KEY_LASTFFUP};
    // 
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fullname, R.id.diagnosis, R.id.lastffup};

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_row, cursor, data, to, 0);
```

from my MainActivity.

Any help will do. Thanks.

Comment: Add an extra " " between the name and the surname you are retrieving?

Comment: When I tried that, it threw some error

Comment: for what you need to concat them?

Comment: @Sajmon to be displayed as one, but I need to put a space between them

Comment: you want to print data from cursor like Uncle Sam where Uncle is value from one column and Sam from another?

Comment: Yes like fname and lname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

```
 public Cursor getAllPatients()
 {
Cursor localCursor = //  
        this.myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME + "|| ' ' ||" + KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP }, null, null, null, null, null);
if (localCursor != null)
  localCursor.moveToFirst();
return localCursor;
}
```

and

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllPatients();
String[] data = new String[]{
        DBHelper.KEY_FNAME + "|| ' ' ||" + DBHelper.KEY_LNAME, DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS, DBHelper.KEY_LASTFFUP};
// 
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fullname, R.id.diagnosis, R.id.lastffup};

dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_row, cursor, data, to, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can concat like this:

```
Cursor localCursor = this.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT (KEY_FNAME  || ' ' || KEY_LNAME) AS fullname, KEY_ID, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP FROM DB_TABLE");
```

Your concated full name will be in the cursor column 'fullname'.

In main activity:

```
String[] data = new String[]{ "fullname", DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS, DBHelper.KEY_LASTFFUP};
```

(You should probably assign a DBHelper constant for "fullname").

Comment: But how about on my MainActivity?

Comment: Simple:   String[] data = new String[]{
            "fullname", DBHelper.KEY_DIAGNOSIS, DBHelper.KEY_LASTFFUP};

Comment: I think it would be something like this `SELECT KEY_FNAME || ' ' || KEY_LNAME as fullname, KEY_ID, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP FROM DB_TABLE`. You can you `Pipe` to concatenate two columns in `SQLite`

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, not sure if this will work on SQLite. Will make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Android Sqlite concat two columns

After a little conversation with author of this thread i suggest you to don't concat columns (you really don't need it) and concat Strings retrieved from Cursor. Your statement will be more human-readable and solution cleaner.

**Explanation:**

Generally is very useful and efficient approach to represent your table on application layer with objects which will represent tables. For example if you had table User, so create new class User and columns in table will be equal to properties in this class. This way is i guess pretty elegant (if someone else will see your code, he won't be confused and scared)

Finally you can simply concat fname and lname when you'll add them to `ListAdapter`

---

So i prefer this way:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
User u = null;
String query = "select * from Table";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   do { 
      u = new User();
      u.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));
      u.setLastName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));
      ...
      users.add(u);
   } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

And then somewhere in `ListAdapter` you can do:

```
textView.setText(u.getFirstname() + " " + u.getLastName());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I kinda dissagree that the solution is cleaner. Selecting exactly what you need is alot cleaner than an unnecessary loop through data. The point of SimpleCursorAdapter is to avoid these loops.

Comment: @VM his is only theory. In real applications is usually used this approach.