# What is the correct syntax in Android studio to concatenating two columns and updating into another column

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, concatenation, multiple-columns

i have a SQLite database table and would like to concatenate two columns and update a third column in the same database with the concatenated string leaving a space between them. i have the general syntax but i just seem to not get it to work. Here are two statements I have.Can someone please point me in the direction of the correct syntax. Many thanks

```
 database.update (ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME, SET ResturantEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION = CONCAT(ResturantEntry.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION));
```

second statement

```
database.update (ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME, SET ResturantEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION = ResturantEntry.COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Sqlite concat two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084724/android-sqlite-concat-two-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the SQLiteDatabase **update** method unless you extracted the data and concatenated it first (due to  how the method  protects against SQL injection (encloses the value in single quotes)). However, you could do this purely through SQL by using something like the following :-

```
    String updtsql = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION + " = " + COLUMN_NAME + "||" + COLUMN_LOCATION + ";";
    database.execSQL(updtsql);
```

- **Note** there is no WHERE clause so this would update every row (as per your code).
- **`||`** is the SQL concatenation operator.

**However, why?**(rhetorical) You are introducing duplication of data as there is no need as you can easily extract the concatenated data.

e.g.

You could extract an ArrayList of all the COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION columns (i.e with the column containing the concatenated data) using :-

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameLocationV1() {
    ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION};
    Cursor csr = database.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION)));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

However, subtly different, extracts exactly the same data but without the costs of the additional column (i.e. the table only needs COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_LOCATION) :-

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameLocationV2() {
    ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    String concatColumnName = COLUMN_NAME + COLUMN_LOCATION;
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_NAME + "||"+COLUMN_LOCATION+" AS " + concatColumnName};
    Cursor csr = database.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(concatColumnName)));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- One difference being a name for the derived column, i.e. `String concatColumnName = COLUMN_NAME + COLUMN_LOCATION;` (could use COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION for this)
- The other difference is instead of providing a column name an expression is used that concatenates the two columns (COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_LOCATION).
- This methodology is more efficient as it reduces the overheads of;

  - the extra disk space required to duplicate the data, and
  - having an extra (unnecessary) process to update the data

Comment: @ MikeT., thankyou for the very detailed responses, thought provoking and various options, and for setting me in the right direction for the most optimal solution. i have tried the first solution and it works, however i am looking into the improved suggestions you mentioned. much appreciated.

Comment: I will use the option of extracting exactly the same data but without the costs of the additional column, as the concatenated data is to be used in a listview report and as you mentioned i can concatenate within the Listview Activity and then populate my listview